# cacls set permission for everyone

Tags: windows, cacls

Scenario is as follows:
-Execute cmd with admin privileges
-mkdir a new folder, let there be jzzz
-How can you grant full privileges to all users in the system, by means of cacls?
**[Note that I mentioned cacls, not icacls]**

I've tried 
`echo S | cacls "C:\\jzzz" /t /g Todos:f`
with no result at all. (Keep in mind it's on a spanish installation, where 'S' stands for 'Y'es and 'Todos' stands fro 'Everyone'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space before the pipe: `echo S| cacls ...`

If you don't want to deal with the different group names you could use a SDDL string instead: `echo Y| cacls "c:\path" /T /S:"D:(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;FA;;;WD)"` You still have to deal with the echo unfortunately and `/S:` sets a new ACL, it does not support `/G`.